# Urls with a value - without a parameter? (Get request)

Tags: php, http, url

I may be completely off base, but I'm pretty sure I've seen URLs structured like this before:

`http://www.example.com/dir/?=1` with no visible parameter being passed, but a value given.

If this is a valid url structure, how would one get the parameter value `1` in PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This value won't be available through `$_GET`. I found it only in `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` or `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. So I assume you have to parse these variables on your own.

Comment: Ah, well that sucks, but is more than understandable. Thanks, I'll accept your offer when the timer drops :).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a quick and dirty function I use to read such URLs

```
function get_url_params() {
    $param_count = 0;
    $params = array();
    foreach (explode('&', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $param) {
        $param = explode('=', $param);

        if ($param[0] == '') {
            $params[$param_count] = $param[1];
        } else {
            $params[$param[0]] = $param[1];
        }

        $param_count++;
    }
    return $params;
}

print_r(get_url_params());
```

Answer (score 1):

you can manually filter the variable from `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` ([documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)) wich schould be `=1` for your example.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely using a rewrite rule .htaccess file. This will translate the request string into whatever the sites scripting expects.

Searching for rewrite engine, rewrite rule and/or .htaccess on this site will result in plenty information on this subject.